# Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i use thymeleaf for html templating with spring. i split layout into 2 pages one for container layout, and the other is fragment. when i call a function from the fragment page. i got **Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined** error. i already include jquery in the container layout head. this is my container layout :

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

    <head>
        <title>Layout</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" th:href="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/dashboard.css}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}">Daily Report</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a th:href="@{/}">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                        <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/' ? 'active':''}" style="cursor: pointer;"><a th:href="@{/}">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/daily' ? 'active':''}" ><a style="cursor: pointer;" th:href="@{/daily}">Daily Report</a></li>
                        <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('formlogout').submit();">Logout</a></li>
                        <form name="formlogout" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" id="formlogout">
                        </form>
                    </ul>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" layout:fragment="content">
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--        th:remove="tag"-->
        <div layout:fragment="custom-footer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my fragment layout:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorator="user/layout">
    <!--      layout:decorate="~{user/layout}">-->
    <!--      layout:decorator="user/layout">-->

    <head>
        <title>Daily Report</title>

        <style>
            .spanhead{
                margin: -10px 0 20px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            }      
            .phead{
                font-size: 35px;
                margin-left: -30px;
            }
            .left{
                margin-left: 30px;
                margin-top: 15px;
            }
            #input_report{
                display:none;
                margin-bottom: 3px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            }

        </style> 


    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content">
            <span class="spanhead col-md-12">
                <p class="phead col-md-10">Daily Report</p> 
                <button type="button" onclick="togleInput()" class="col-md-2 btn btn-default left">Input Report</button>
            </span>
            <div id="input_report">
                <form class="form-inline" name="formreport" th:action="@{/daily}" method="post" id="formreport">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tanggal">Tanggal : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tanggal" id="tanggal" title="tanggal" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px;">
                        <label for="uraian">Uraian : </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="uraian" id="uraian" title="uraian" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:30px;">Submit</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Tanggal</th>
                            <th>Uraian</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>3/1/2017</td>
                            <td>Desain Mock Up Aplikasi</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3/2/2017</td>
                            <td>Desain database Aplikasi</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div layout:fragment="custom-footer">
            <script th:inline="javascript">
                function togleInput()
                {
                     $('#input_report').toggle();
                }
                console.log('hai');

            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i click the button in fragment layout. the function got error because $ is not defined. i'm new to spring and thymeleaf please help me to solve this thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$` to see if jQuery is there

Comment: already tried that too

Answer (score 0):

You should put all scripts at the bottom before `</body>`, so the page loads faster and try putting your function in a `$(document).ready(function () {` to ensure nothing happends in the wrong order, you want your function to apply to the elements on the page which is loaded at document ready

EDIT: you must put jquery before your functions/scripts if you're going to use jquery, such as " $ " in the scripts.